# Circular dependency between types in Fortran module

Tags: module, fortran

I don't know how exactly circular dependencies are resolved in Fortran modules. The following module compiles with ifort-2016 and gfortran-4.9

```
module types
   implicit none
   type type1
      type(type2), pointer :: t2
   end type type1

   type type2
      type(type1)          :: t1
      integer              :: x
   end type type2
end module
```

but if I change the definition order to

```
module types
   implicit none
   type type2
      type(type1)          :: t1
      integer              :: x
   end type type2

   type type1
      type(type2), pointer :: t2
   end type type1
end module
```

I get the following error

```
error #6457: This derived type name has not been declared.   [TYPE1]
      type(type1)          :: t1
```

the behaviour is the same with ifort-2016 and gfortran-4.9.
Since there are similar circular dependencies in both modules why does the first one compile but the second one doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between the working and not-working code is the location of the type with the `pointer` attribute of the component.  It's this attribute that allows a type declaration to refer to a type that has not been previously defined.

Look at

```
type type2
  type(type1)          :: t1
  integer              :: x
end type type2
```

Here the `type1` component of type `type2` hasn't the `pointer` attribute.  That means that the type `type1` must have been previously defined.  In your first, working, example that is the case.  In your second, broken, example, it isn't.

Looking at the other type

```
type type1
   type(type2), pointer :: t2
end type type1
```

the `type2` component has the pointer attribute.  So, the type `type2` needn't have been defined before this reference.  You can see this in action in both examples.

This requirement is stated in the Fortran 2008 standard as

> C440 (R436) If neither the POINTER nor the ALLOCATABLE attribute is specified, the declaration-type-spec in the component-def-stmt shall specify an intrinsic type or a previously defined derived type.

---

I've restricted attention here to the `pointer` attribute.  As the quote suggests, the same holds with the `allocatable` attribute.  Allowing this later reference with `allocatable` is new in Fortran 2008: in Fortran 2003 the `pointer` attribute was required.  As Vladimir F comments, this new freedom (which provides for recursive allocatable components) is not implemented in all compilers.  In the above read "`pointer` or `allocatable`" where appropriate.

Comment: Just as a note, many compilers still do not implement the exception in C440 for ALLOCATABLE, only for POINTER.

Comment: Good point.  I've (erroneously) been thinking that `allocatable` was new in F2008 only for recursive definitions, but that's just a specific example of the "previously defined".  In F2003 only `pointer` was allowed in such cases generally.