# Pointer or allocatable for type components

Tags: pointers, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation, intel-fortran

Say you have a declared type `dat1` which has a default numbers of members. Depending on run time, this `dat1` may or may not be extended with other types. This is easy as you can use the `extends` feature. However, if you have an array of `dat1` and some elements of that array may or may not want to inherit another type - how is this done most reasonably.

I have the following example:

```
type dat1 

  real :: x(3)
  type(dat2), allocatable :: rnd 
  type(dat1), pointer :: next => dat1
end dat1
```

Now I used a linked list to do this. My question is basically if it is the correct way to declare the second type `rnd` as an allocatable, and then just allocate it whenever a node requests it. 
The other option is to declare it as a pointer i.e. `type(dat2), allocatable :: rnd`, now is there any significant differences, despite the common Fortran differences with pointers vs alloctables like explicit/implicit deallocation, contiguous memory etc.

Note that no matter what, each `dat1` node will always have either 0 or 1 `rnd` type attached to it.
I was considering during runtime that I would check if `rnd` was allocated or for pointer it would be associated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components of a derived type have the same [concerns as general pointer/allocatable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2300199/3157076).

However, there are additional aspects of interest regarding components:

- [automatic deallocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29038025/3157076): on deallocating a derived type object any allocated allocatable components are deallocated; pointer components are not automatically deallocated or disassociated.
- [type references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36884505/3157076): both pointer and allocatable components may be of the type being defined (here `dat1`) or defined at a later point, but for allocatable components this is a feature not available before Fortran 2008 and is not massively supported by compilers.

One difference not mentioned in the linked question's answer is relevant to this question.  Here you say:

> I was considering during runtime that I would check if rnd was allocated or for pointer it would be associated

It is always allowed to ask `ALLOCATED(x%rnd)` (allocatable), but it is not always allowed to ask `ASSOCIATED(x%rnd)` (pointer).  A pointer component may be of undefined association status whereas an allocatable component will always have defined allocation status.<sup>1</sup>

You may therefore want to set an initial association status of the pointer component.

---

<sup>1</sup>The case of undefined allocation status (of Fortran 90) and allocatable components have never co-existed in the standard.